# Can someone find my EC2 information?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, privacy

I have an AWS EC2 instance and I run a nodejs server for a website. You can easily find out the IP and the service provider (in my case Amazon), but my question is: can you find out more information (i.e. name, country) about the person who owns the VM?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Luca, is my answer ok for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless legal actions are taken against you, Amazon won't give any information about you.

On the security part, it's pretty good. https://aws.amazon.com/security/
But I would say the weakest part is how you configure your instance and what kind of data you write on it.

And of course the same thing applies to your AWS account. Make sure no one can access it by choosing a very strong password and using 2 factor auth.